# How can I create a list of model relationships in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

If I have a table called Master Index which has for example : Country Name = " USA ", and I want to have several models linked to it (GDP,Population,Inequality,etc) , how do I define that list of models in a field so that I can know which properties does that Country has?

Let me know if its possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can read [HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent)

First you need to create table but make it in migration that the table you will create is base on the hierarchy example:

If you have `Master Index` as your general root of relationship young need to make it first in the migration. It will look like this on your `Database > Migrations` folder.

```
2020_07_14_0000001_create_master_indexs_table.php
2020_07_14_0000001_create_gdps_table.php
2020_07_14_0000001_create_populations_table.php
2020_07_14_0000001_create_inequalities_table.php
```

**Master Index Model**

You will specify the relationship it should look like this:

```php
public function gdps() {
  return $this->hasMany(Gdp::class); // if you have different foreign key you can specify it in the next argument return [$this->hasMany(Gdp::class, 'gdp_id');] like this
}

public function populations() {
  return $this->hasMany(Population::class);
}

public function inequalities() {
  return $this->hasMany(Inequality::class);
}
```

**GDPS Model / Populations Model / Inequality Model**

You need to specify where it belongs. It should be like this.

```php
public function master_index() {
  return $this->belongsTo(MasterIndex::class);
}
```

**GDPS Migration / Population Migration / Inequality Migration**

In your migration you should specify the foreign key.

If you're using **Laravel 7.x** you can do like this.

```php
$table->foreignId('master_index_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
```

If you're not familiar with the above code you can do also like this:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('master_index_id');

$table->foreign('master_index_id')->references('id')->on('master_indexs')->onDelete('cascade');
```